# Unknown field ChannelEntry

Tags: php-errors

After upgrading Expression Engine, we are receiving errors related to a translations channel.  This error appears on the entries edit page.  The page loads fine on the front end, but is un editable through the backend due to the error.  This error only occurs within the specific channel of "Translations", where all other entries outside of this channel are fully manageable.

**ERROR**

```
Exception Caught
Unknown field ChannelEntry.
/home/...../public_html/system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Select.php:297
```

**TRACE**

```
#0 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Select.php(202): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Select->translateProperty(NULL)
#1 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Select.php(88): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Select->applyOrders(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Database\Query), Array)
#2 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Select.php(42): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Select->buildQuery()
#3 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/DataStore.php(501): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Select->run()
#4 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/DataStore.php(447): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\DataStore->runQuery('Select', Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder))
#5 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Builder.php(150): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\DataStore->selectQuery(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder))
#6 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Builder.php(74): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder->fetch()
    #7 ee/EllisLab/Addons/relationship/ft.relationship.php(544): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder->all()
    #8 ee/legacy/fieldtypes/EE_Fieldtype.php(359): Relationship_ft->display_field('0')
    #9 [internal function]: EE_Fieldtype->display_publish_field('0')
    #10 ee/legacy/libraries/api/Api_channel_fields.php(400): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Content/FieldFacade.php(205): Api_channel_fields->apply('display_publish...', Array)
#12 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Content/Display/FieldDisplay.php(54): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\FieldFacade->getForm()
#13 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/View/publish/entry.php(135): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\Display\FieldDisplay->getForm()
#14 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/View/View.php(145): include('/home/...../p...')
#15 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/View/View.php(110): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\View\View->parse('/home/...../p...', Array)
#16 ee/legacy/libraries/View.php(51): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\View\View->render(Array)
#17 ee/legacy/libraries/Cp.php(241): View->render('publish/entry', Array, false)
#18 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Publish/Edit.php(478): Cp->render('publish/entry', Array)
#19 [internal function]: EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Publish\Edit->entry('1499')
#20 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(192): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(94): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->runController(Array)
#22 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php(139): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->run(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Request))
#23 /home/...../public_html/admin.php(143): require_once('/home/...../p...')
#23 /home/...../public_html/admin.php(143): require_once('/home/...../p...')
```

If anyone has any advice on where to start that would be great!

Comment: It might help to add what version you upgraded from -> to? Also, are there any fields being used in the Translations channel that are unique to that channel (i.e.: a 3rd party field type only used there)?

Comment: We upgraded from 2.5.5 to 3.3.3 - There are no fields unique to this channel.

Comment: Then I would contact EllisLab support on this or maybe start with a bug report https://support.ellislab.com/bugs ?

Comment: Thank you, I have submitted a report and will try to remember to post the results, or at least a link to the results here later on.  For anyone searching ellis lab, the bug report has been submitted with the same title here.